# How to retrive jquery slide show images from database?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrive camera jquery slide show from database. But it's not working. Anyone out there please help me since I'm just learning.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/camera.min.js'></script> 
<script>
    jQuery(function(){          
        jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
            thumbnails: true
        });
        jQuery('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
            height: '400px',
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="fluid_container">

<?php
$fetch_sql = "SELECT slider_name, slider_caption FROM tbl_slider WHERE slider_type = '1' ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 4";
$fetch_result= mysql_query($fetch_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($fetch_row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_result))
{
$slider_name = $fetch_row['slider_name'];
$slider_caption = $fetch_row['slider_caption'];
if($slider_name != null)
{
echo"<div class='camera_wrap camera_azure_skin' id='camera_wrap_1'> <div data-thumb='images/$slider_name' data-src='images/$slider_name'> <img src='images/$slider_name' alt='$slider_name'> </div>   ";
}
echo"<div class='camera_caption fadeFromBottom'> $slider_caption </div> </div>";
}
?>      
   </div>
```

Comment: what is problem with this problem then?

Comment: Only 1 image displays. I want to display 4 images.

Comment: where do you want to display image then ? i dont see where you are putting image in HTML

Comment: sorry I was engaged in other work. I've included this php file to my index file

Comment: Paste your code where you are setting img src

Comment: I've extracted images from the images folder. You can see it in the echo section of the above code.

Comment: paste What output $slider_name  is giving?

Comment: Use this code=>         echo '<div class=\'camera_wrap camera_azure_skin\' id=\'camera_wrap_1\'> <div data-thumb=\'images/$slider_name\' data-src=\'images/$slider_name\'> <img src=\'images/'+$slider_name+' alt='+$slider_name+'> </div>   ';

Comment: It's displaying only 1 image of the slide show

Comment: there may be only 1 image in DB

Comment: No there are several images. I've just limit to 4. Each time I refresh page different image displays coz I've used RAND(). I replaced your code but instead of displaying images, only text displayed like this:    +11394209523.jpg+
bridge
+11394212257.jpg+
water
+11394212239.jpg+
sky
+11394207619.jpg+
mountain

Comment: This is output of which code ? provide line

Comment: It's output of the 1st echo section.

Comment: JPG images are inserted to database on slider_name. The above code you gave just displayed the database entered name of JPG file. I need extract the JPG images which I've entered on database.

Comment: Then please provide Output you are getting  inside                                 <div data-thumb='images/$slider_name' data-src='images/$slider_name'> <img src='images/$slider_name' alt='$slider_name'> </div>

Comment: It shows like this: 
+11394209523.jpg+
bridge
+11394212257.jpg+
sky
+11394212239.jpg+
water
+11394207619.jpg+
mountain

Comment: instead of this text"+11394209523.jpg" image of a bridge should be displayed.

Comment: Output of <div data-thumb='images/$slider_name' data-src='images/$slider_name'> <img src='images/$slider_name' alt='$slider_name'> </div> is:  only one image among bridge, sky, water and mountain with jquery effect

Comment: Isn't there any solution for my problem??